# How to debug word vsto add-in?

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging, ms-word, vsto

Currently when I start the plugin the breakpoint on the definition of the handler of Me.Startup gets hit.

But the breakpoint on the definition of Application.DocumentOpen never gets triggered when I open an existing word document.

I looked online and microsoft wants us to debug this type of project using MessageBoxes, but surely there must be a better way? Is it even possible?

Upon further research using AddinSpy it turns out that I am meaning an Add-in ALL path, however the path is specified and is seen by the AddinSpy. Where does it expect the dll to be?

Comment: What's the link to the Microsoft suggestion? Are you running this in Debug mode, or from an installation on a machine other than your developer machine?

Comment: i am running it in debug mode on my developer machine

Comment: and the link to "mcirosoft wants us to..."?

Comment: Also, please show us the Startup and DocumentOpen code.

Comment: there is no code in the startup and my breakpoint is before any of the code in the document open gets called as the breakpoint is on the definition of the handler itself, same as on me.startup.

Comment: That link is to an article on Add-ins for Visual Studio, not VSTO/Office, so it's not really relevant. What all do you have in your Add-in besides Startup and Document_Open method signatures? Do you have any code at all? A Ribbon? It sounds like your Add-in is not loading successfully.

Comment: We have a what looks like a vb winform as our only control. it ends up being a pane in the right side of the word window. I can see the add-in in the settings->addins but for some reason it is not running any other code besides start up even when i open a document. The code inside app open seems to be opening that winform but seems irrelevent to me as that event handler is never being called.

Comment: That would be a custom task pane. That appears? Does the code linked to it (a button, perhaps) run? I'm not familiar with "settings/addins" - please be more precise in your terminology.

Comment: The custom task pane does not appear. All the code linked to it exists within the pane and cannot be run because the pane is not running, so buttons tables etc. Which terminology needs more description in particular?

Answer (score 1):

> But the breakpoint on the definition of Application.DocumentOpen never gets triggered when I open an existing word document.

Where and when do you subscribe to the DocumentOpen event of the Application class? What code exactly do you use?

Anyway, I'd recommend using the [Debug.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) statements in the code to see what happens under the hood. See [How to trace and debug in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788) for more information.

Comment: I subscribe to these events in my AddIn.vb file, in visual studio it has a little world icon rotated about 45% in the z direction next to the file name in solution explorer so i assume this is my addin base. Using print statements wont help me as I can never get into the events in the first place.

Comment: Then the event is fired before you are subscribed to it. Try to check out the Documents collection when the add-in is loaded. Thus, you may imitate the first event if you can't reach it so early.

Comment: The first event being Me.Startup? That one I am subscribed to as my breakpoint is being hit. The breakpoint that I am concerned with is Me.Application.DocumentOpen

Comment: Try to check out the Documents collection before subscribing to the event. Most probably the document is already opened (before the Startup event is fired).

Comment: Then why am i able to beak on the startup? I am not having problems with the startup, but document open is giving me issues.

Comment: The DocumentOpen event may fire before the Startup function where you subscribe to the event.

Comment: There should be no Application.DocumentOpen events before Me.Startup though surely, since no documents have been open. When i click run it open word and hits Me.Startup but when i open a document it never hits Application.DocumentOpen